# How to replace color A into B using Meshmixer

Tags: cad, color, freecad, meshmixer

I have a `.mix` file with multicolored objects. Using Meshmixer, I would like to change the surface color A into color B without modifying the rest of the colors.

In theory, this could be done by first selecting only the surfaces matching the color A, and then use the **Sculpt** > **Color** tool to paint the selection into B color without changing the rest of the surfaces. Or there could be a dedicated tool that can more automatically paint only the surfaces matching the selected A color into B color leaving the other surfaces unmodified. However, to my surprise, I haven't found any good guidelines to do this simple task of turning color A into color B. I noticed the promising **Select** > **Filters** > **Expand Mode** > **Vertex Color Similarity** option but have no idea how it should work or is it suitable for the job at all. Additional information can be found in Autodesk's guide on Meshmixer's [Filters Panel](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MSHMXR/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-D5CCD7BF-0E74-4B2D-9307-8397A5DCA5E7).

Any help? I also have FreeCAD if that could help, but it cannot open `.mix` files at least directly.

Update: I read the **Vertex Color Similarity** documentation more carefully and get a little bit further. I am using a Mac and instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> I need to hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> while right-clicking the pre-existing selection (within a surface matching the color A) and then drag to expand the selected area. However, the selection in the isolated color area (let's call this A1) does not expand into a separate color area (A2, as said in the documentation: "grows the selection to connected regions"). It would be a tedious task to click and select all the individual areas representing the color A (area A1, A2, A3, A4, and so on) and then do the expansion. How could I more easily select and modify **all** the surfaces matching the color A?